# Why does MVC JavaScript Sticky Menu only work when not using /controller/action in URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, menu, slideshow

I'm using MVC 5 and have imported an HTML5 rich template from the web that I purchased.  I successfully ported the application from plain HTML with JavaScript to fit with how MVC deals with scripts and routing.  I'm not doing any custom routing within the application so the standard /controller/action way of handling URLs is still intact.  It all works perfectly when I navigate to the main URL with no path localhost:.  It all works perfectly when I navigate to the home controller with no action: localhost:/home.

Here is where the question comes in.    Only a couple of the JavaScript functions fail to work when I actually use an action call in the URL such as localhost:/home/index.

Why would it work perfectly until you specify an action, then suddenly only a couple of the features fail?  Several animations and all styling seems to be intact.  There are an awful lot of JavaScript files to get to the code, but the two that aren't functioning are a sticky menu "tmstickup.js" (not sure where this came from) and the camera slideshow from Pixedelic: www.pixedelic.com.

Here is the snippet of the menu code I am using in the _Layout.cshtml.  The menu just scrolls off the screen in the failed scenario, not docking itself at the top as expected.

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="stuck_container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="grid_4">
                    <h1>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")"><img src="~/Content/images/logo.png" alt="discov" /></a>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_8">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="sf-menu">
                            <li class="current">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")<strong></strong></li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")<strong></strong></li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services and prices", "Services", "Home")<strong></strong></li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Order online", "Order", "Home")<strong></strong></li>
                            <li id="last-li">@Html.ActionLink("Contact us", "Contact", "Home")<strong></strong></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is the code from my Home/Index.cshtml.  None of the images show up and all the three sets of verbiage just display on top of each other.

```
<div class="camera_main_container  wow fadeIn">
    <div class="slider_wrapper">
        <div class="" id="camera_wrap">
            <div data-src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/slide1.jpg")">
                <div class="caption fadeIn">
                    <div class="caption_bg">
                        <span class="slider_txt1">Let professional </span>
                        <span class="slider_txt2">appraiser help you </span>
                        <span class="slider_txt3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco. in voluptate.</span>
                        <a href="#" class="camera_more_btn">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-src=@Url.Content("~/Content/images/slide2.jpg")>
                <div class="caption fadeIn">
                    <div class="caption_bg">
                        <span class="slider_txt1">Discover the </span>
                        <span class="slider_txt2 color4">value of your home</span>
                        <span class="slider_txt3 color4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco. in voluptate.</span>
                        <a href="#" class="camera_more_btn v2">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-src=@Url.Content("~/Content/images/slide3.jpg")>
                <div class="caption fadeIn">
                    <div class="caption_bg">
                        <span class="slider_txt1">You should know</span>
                        <span class="slider_txt2 color4">the price</span>
                        <span class="slider_txt3 color4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco. in voluptate.</span>
                        <a href="#" class="camera_more_btn v2">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem.  There was an extra CSS class I put at the top by accident which caused the nested CSS classes to no longer hit.  DOH